# Error when add CSRF token to Laravel form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a login form in Laravel:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="{{ URL::route('adminAuthen') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Admin Login</h2>
    <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

But I always got error when visit this form:

```
Call to undefined function csrf_field()
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: whats `csrf_field` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there is no function called `csrf_field()` in laravel 5, use this instead of that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Update 2016-03-17**

Laravel introduce [`csrf_field()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) in `version 5.1`

`{{ csrf_field() }}` this will generate csrf token field,

Comment: I read on the master document page of Laravel and it say about csrf_field() but  when I switch to 5.0 document, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your `{{ csrf_field() }}` with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

You might have misunderstood this because of master documentation page of laravel. I don't why they did that. But this one is what I found to be working on the laravel-5.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2018-10-01**

in latest versions of laravel use:

```
@csrf
```

and you'll be good to go!
P/S. i use 5.7

Answer (score 1):

The function `csrf_field()` isn't in regular Laravel 5 yet, even though it's on the [master documentation page](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication). You can use the helper `csrf_token()` instead, see e.g. the [helpers documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#miscellaneous), and then build the field yourself from that - or create a template for it, or similar.